# Unicode character saved as ? in MySQL SQLAlchemy (Warning: Incorrect string value)

Tags: python, mysql, csv, unicode, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save string with the character "é" from a csv into my database.

This is the error

```
 lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:425: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\x8Ert' for column 'last_name' at row 1
```

This is how I'm reading the CSV:

```
    response = requests.get(fileurl)
    order_data = csv.DictReader(response.iter_lines())
```

Then I save each row into the database.

The original string for the last_name is 'Rob\x8ert' (Robért).

Yes, the table is utf8mb4_general_ci, and so are the columns.

The column in my model:

```
last_name = db.Column(db.String(80, convert_unicode=True))
```

I tried removing convert_unicode=True, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Check the page encoding.
On DB connexion SET it to UTF-8

Comment: What generated the CSV file?  That is an unusual way to encode it.

Comment: Does it actually have the 4 characters `\x8E`?  Or is something escaping a single 8-bit character?  If you can get the length of the string, you can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

"é" is U+00E9, not U+008E. Decode the string from... whichever encoding it's actually using before attempting to store it.

Comment: How can I figure that out? It's just a regular CSV file.

Comment: Ask whoever generated the file.